# Regular expression for float to distinguish from dates

Tags: regex, floating-point, numbers

I need detect in the text the floating point numbers. I researched many solutions, but all not work correctly for my case. I have in the text the numbers :

```
.34

0.34

23.54
```

but I have too the date in the format: dd.mm.yyyy

The problem is that many solutions detect date from text as float too. In the final I need replace in the text the dot with comma only for numbers, not for date

Comment: what? show me where found the solutions? maybe my english is bad?

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Differing the dates from a float shouldn't be a problem if you set starts/ends-with for your expressions.

Comment: [\-\+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?

Comment: (?=.+)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `(?<= )(\d+)?\.(\d+)?(?= )` . that used look-around to match float numbers between 2 spaces !

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eQ2kY0/3)

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but this match 03.04.2014 as float too :( I need match only numbers

Comment: :) on the rubular.com you can test my text "hello, my byrthdate is 03.04.1999 and I have 78.6 kg", I need detect "78.6" only

Comment: Strange, on the rubular.com not working, let me test in the php

Answer (score 1):

Try `(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )` for matching just floating point numbers. It should not match date numbers.